# why the following c program is giving segmentation error?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

I tried running following C program and got `Segmentation fault`, I am not getting where the code is wrong, the output is saying  `Program finished with exit code 139`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *a[] = {"s1","s2"};
  printf("\n S==>>> %s",*a[0]);
}
```

Comment: `*a[0]` is a `char`. `%s` requires a `char *`. You probably want just `a[0]`.

Comment: Also, review the compiler warnings. Should get something like: `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]`

Answer (score 2):

```
   printf("\n S==>>> %s",*a[0]);
```

Should be

```
 printf("\n S==>>> %c",*a[0]);  // *a[0] is of type char
```

Or

```
 printf("\n S==>>> %s",a[0]); // a[0] is of type char *
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a[0]` has the type `char *` due to the declaration of the array `a`.

```
char *a[] = {"s1","s2"};
```

So the expression `*a[0]` has the type `char`.  However the format specifier `%s` expects an object of the type `char *`. As a result the function `printf` considers the numeric value of the character `'s'`  as a memory address.

So instead use

```
printf("\n S==>>> %s", a[0]);
```

or even

```
printf("\n S==>>> %s", *a );
```

because used in expressions (with rare exceptions) an array designator is converted to pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1):

First of All the Correct approach code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
   char *a[] = {"s1","s2"};
   printf("\n S==>>> %s",a[0]);
}
```

Second this you are storing "s1" string in a[0] and string "s2" in a[1]. So if you if want to print the string it would be like above.

If you try to add * or & before pointer then it would point to the address of the pointer and for printing the address %d is used. Now if incorrectly code then it will certainly show an error

Answer (score 1):

The line

`printf("\n S==>>> %s",*a[0]);`

is wrong.

You can write either `*a` or `a[0]` (both are equivalent), but `*a[0]` is equivalent to `a[0][0]`, which is just a char, i.e. a single character. Since you specified that you are printing a string in your `printf` format string, you must specify a string, i.e. a null terminated character array, instead of a single character.

If you  want to print a single character instead of a whole string, then you must specify `%c` in the `printf` format string instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

While all the other answers are right about the correct usage I want to further explain why exactly you get a segmentation error.

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *a[] = {"s1","s2"};
  printf("\n S==>>> %s",*a[0]);
}
```

tries to print the string `\n S==>>> s1` but fails especially with a segmentation fault, because the access of `*a[0]` results in the address `0x73` since the hex value of the `s` is `0x73`.
And the address `0x73` is not mapped within your process address space, thus leading to a `segmentation fault` since you basically try to print a string at address `0x73`.